# Edge couldn't access simple popup reference

Tags: reference, microsoft-edge, popupwindow

I try to get the reference of a popup to attach a listener. In Chrome and Firefox, I've no problems, only Microsoft edge make problems, put out `access denied`.

Following declaration return nothing or a null object. In chrome, I get an new window object.

```
pop = window.open('http://msn.com', 'mysite','');
```

Is that an edge model security problem? I've tried to change the trusted zone in `Settings`.

```
//complete simple code
    pop = window.open('http://msn.com', 'mysite','');
    pop.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        console.log('loading stuff');
                        event.returnValue='';
                    });
```

> Permission denied SCRIPT70: Permission denied    eval code (6) (2,1)

[image of errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhhJr.png)

Comment: I try to make a test with your code in MS Edge. I did not get 'permission denied' error. I got an error for undefined and null reference. Here is a testing result : https://i.postimg.cc/d0cMWsY4/10.gif Check whether any group policy was applied which deny your permission in Edge. Try to make a test with other machine which have Edge to check the result.

Comment: ok, thanks - but null reference or undefined ? Should i doesnt get the reference of window?